# 'top' commant is inconsistent with system monitor

Tags: 20.04, cpu, process, cpu-load, system-monitor

System monitor tells me that CPU load is at 20% but when I use the 'top' command the sum of %CPU is way above 20% and sometimes even exceeds 100%. Why is this the case? I am using an Intel i5 processor with 4 cores and 2 threads per core if that's useful.

Furthermore, there is a particular process that has a command name of 'frontend' which always uses around 50 %CPU, can anyone explain what this is ? Is appears to run even when I close all my applications.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAjAu.png) is what 'top' command outputs (while system monitor shows a 20% CPU load), along with the 'frontend' process I refer to.

Comment: Top counts each core usage giving 800% in all for a 8 core system, whereas System monitor shows overall load, giving up to 100% for the combined CPU resources.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know what the `frontend` process is? Because it uses quite some load compared to the rest of processes.

Comment: I have nu idea ... but if you find the pid-number of the frontend process and run `ls .lo /proc/<pid>/exe`  .. ex. `ls -l /proc/23456/exe` .. it will give you the filename the process originates from. maybe that can help.

Comment: It outputs `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  7 12:45 /proc/5422/exe -> /usr/bin/perl`. What does `->` mean ?

Comment: That the executable is linked to / pointing to /usr/bin/perl. Sorry if it isn't useful to you.

Comment: No worries, thank you anyway.